# How to bulk insert records in Sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I need to insert multiple records (thousands of them) into database using SQFlite package in Flutter. Each record contains around 50 columns (attributes of an Employee like name, date of birth, address, mobile number etc.). Assuming there is a class named Employee and i have a list of employees that i need to insert locally:

```
Class Employee {
  String name;
  String address;
  String mobileNumber;
  // ... and many more fields
  }

// And then i have a list of employees
List<Employee> employees = await fetchEmployeesFromNetwork();
```

As far as i could research, there is no bulkInsert method available in the SQFlite package and i could only find the following ways:

1. iterating through the employees list and using batch insert to insert the employees one by one in a batch like this

```
await db.transaction((txn)async {
    var batch = txn.batch();
    for (var emp in employees) {
        batch.insert(employeeTable, emp.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    }
    await batch.commit();
  });
```

**OR**

2. using rawInsert to generate a single statement and insert in one go like this

```
INSERT INTO 'employees' ('column1', 'column2', /* and other columns */) VALUES
                ('data1', 'data2'),
                ('data1', 'data2'),
                ('data1', 'data2');
```

The question i want to ask is which method is better in terms of performance etc. (or is it just a matter of preference?), and is there any other method/way specifically for bulk insertion of records in SQFlite?

Answer (score 0):

Both the cases haves it's pros and cons,

If in your case there are very large amount of data then the raw query would be better and faster but if some error occurs in the insertion there's not support for rollbacks.

Rather in the using batch it treat the operations as a single transection so rollback would be possible and it's secure too.

So at the end it comes to you, it's on your requirement.